# How to capture requests and responses in Playwright after hitting a button?

Tags: javascript, webautomation, playwright

I have the following Playwright code :

```
await page.goto(API_URL + "/login/");
await page.type('input[name="userName"]', username);
await page.type('input[name="password"]', password);
await page.click('button#submit');
```

what happens, it goes to about three redirects. Last redirect is to a pseudoaddress (basically a string) that contains credentials data. I need to extract that. How can I achieve that?

Comment: How about using waitForURL with some mask?

Comment: @hardkoded there is no waitForURL in playwright framework

Comment: Right, wait a few days for v1.11 :)

Comment: I see ;) I actually found the answer that worked for me, see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One needs to add:

```
 const response = await page.waitForRequest(url => url.url().includes('templateFrom3rdRedirect'));
```

where `'templateFrom3rdRedirect'` is the part of URL unique to the necessary "hop" of the last redirect, that captures call to pseudo-url (that is later found at `response.url()`).